# turtlebot4 simulation stuck at Requesting list of world names

Tags: gazebo, ros2, turtlebot, turtlebot4

I am trying to run turtlebot4 on ROS2 humble with an ignition gazebo installed on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine.

when I run the command

```
ros2 launch turtlebot4_ignition_bringup turtlebot4_ignition.launch.py
```

here is the output:

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/abdosalm/.ros/log/2023-11-10-22-37-52-587707-abdosalm-Alienware-m17-R3-47184
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
ign_args is deprecated, migrate to gz_args!
[INFO] [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1]: process started with pid [47187]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-2]: process started with pid [47190]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [47192]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-4]: process started with pid [47195]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-5]: process started with pid [47197]
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-6]: process started with pid [47199]
[INFO] [create-7]: process started with pid [47201]
[INFO] [create-8]: process started with pid [47203]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-9]: process started with pid [47205]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-10]: process started with pid [47209]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-11]: process started with pid [47212]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-12]: process started with pid [47215]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-13]: process started with pid [47217]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-14]: process started with pid [47219]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-15]: process started with pid [47221]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-16]: process started with pid [47229]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-17]: process started with pid [47253]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-18]: process started with pid [47256]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-19]: process started with pid [47258]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-20]: process started with pid [47277]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-21]: process started with pid [47292]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-22]: process started with pid [47334]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-23]: process started with pid [47375]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-24]: process started with pid [47379]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-25]: process started with pid [47433]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-26]: process started with pid [47450]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-27]: process started with pid [47461]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-28]: process started with pid [47486]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-29]: process started with pid [47502]
[INFO] [turtlebot4_node-30]: process started with pid [47508]
[INFO] [turtlebot4_ignition_hmi_node-31]: process started with pid [47519]
[INFO] [spawner-32]: process started with pid [47571]
[INFO] [hazards_vector_publisher-33]: process started with pid [47591]
[INFO] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34]: process started with pid [47618]
[INFO] [motion_control-35]: process started with pid [47620]
[INFO] [wheel_status_publisher-36]: process started with pid [47622]
[INFO] [mock_publisher-37]: process started with pid [47624]
[INFO] [robot_state-38]: process started with pid [47626]
[INFO] [kidnap_estimator_publisher-39]: process started with pid [47639]
[INFO] [ui_mgr-40]: process started with pid [47651]
[INFO] [pose_republisher_node-41]: process started with pid [47653]
[INFO] [sensors_node-42]: process started with pid [47655]
[INFO] [interface_buttons_node-43]: process started with pid [47657]
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-44]: process started with pid [47659]
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-45]: process started with pid [47686]
[parameter_bridge-2] [INFO] [1699648676.439669965] [clock_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/clock (ignition.msgs.Clock) -> /clock (rosgraph_msgs/msg/Clock)] (Lazy 0)
[robot_state_publisher-3] [WARN] [1699648676.330157552] [kdl_parser]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330368347] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330511260] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment bump_front_center
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330527167] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment bump_front_left
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330535320] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment bump_front_right
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330542023] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment bump_left
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330548774] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment bump_right
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330555203] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment bumper
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330560655] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment button_1
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330566547] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment button_2
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330572557] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment button_power
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330578928] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment cliff_front_left
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330584600] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment cliff_front_right
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330589712] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment cliff_side_left
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330594589] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment cliff_side_right
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330599778] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment front_caster_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330604867] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment front_left_bottom_weight_block
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330610250] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment front_left_top_weight_block
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330615511] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment front_left_tower_standoff
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330629963] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment front_right_bottom_weight_block
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330635304] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment front_right_top_weight_block
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330640329] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment front_right_tower_standoff
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330645272] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment imu_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330651041] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment ir_intensity_front_center_left
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330656157] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment ir_intensity_front_center_right
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330661214] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment ir_intensity_front_left
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330666583] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment ir_intensity_front_right
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330672445] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment ir_intensity_left
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330678315] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment ir_intensity_right
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330684389] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment ir_intensity_side_left
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330689720] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment ir_omni
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330695396] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment left_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330701656] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment mouse
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330707221] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment oakd_camera_bracket
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330712305] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment oakd_imu_frame
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330719191] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment oakd_left_camera_frame
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330725103] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment oakd_left_camera_optical_frame
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330731057] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment oakd_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330737455] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment oakd_rgb_camera_frame
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330743046] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment oakd_rgb_camera_optical_frame
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330749292] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment oakd_right_camera_frame
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330755606] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment oakd_right_camera_optical_frame
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330761655] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment rear_left_tower_standoff
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330767887] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment rear_right_tower_standoff
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330773844] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment right_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330779820] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment rplidar_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330817386] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment shell_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330826894] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment tower_sensor_plate
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330833317] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_drop_left
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1699648676.330839375] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_drop_right
[robot_state_publisher-5] [WARN] [1699648676.326064922] [kdl_parser]: The root link std_dock_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[robot_state_publisher-5] [INFO] [1699648676.326134379] [dock_state_publisher]: got segment green_buoy_link
[robot_state_publisher-5] [INFO] [1699648676.326175158] [dock_state_publisher]: got segment halo_link
[robot_state_publisher-5] [INFO] [1699648676.326183807] [dock_state_publisher]: got segment red_buoy_link
[robot_state_publisher-5] [INFO] [1699648676.326190131] [dock_state_publisher]: got segment std_dock_link
[robot_state_publisher-5] [INFO] [1699648676.326196147] [dock_state_publisher]: got segment yellow_buoy_link
[static_transform_publisher-6] [WARN] [1699648676.311550345] []: Old-style arguments are deprecated; see --help for new-style arguments
[static_transform_publisher-6] [INFO] [1699648676.324690567] [tf_odom_std_dock_link_publisher]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-6] translation: ('0.157000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-6] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-6] from 'odom' to 'std_dock_link'
[create-7] [ros_ign_gazebo] is deprecated! Redirecting to use [ros_gz_sim] instead!
[create-7] 
[create-7] [INFO] [1699648676.353334216] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[create-8] [ros_ign_gazebo] is deprecated! Redirecting to use [ros_gz_sim] instead!
[create-8] 
[create-8] [INFO] [1699648676.354122597] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[parameter_bridge-9] [INFO] [1699648676.403434603] [cmd_vel_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/cmd_vel (ignition.msgs.Twist) -> /cmd_vel (geometry_msgs/msg/Twist)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-9] [INFO] [1699648676.423733816] [cmd_vel_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/model/turtlebot4/cmd_vel (geometry_msgs/msg/Twist) -> /model/turtlebot4/cmd_vel (ignition.msgs.Twist)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-10] [INFO] [1699648676.411263284] [pose_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/model/turtlebot4/pose (ignition.msgs.Pose_V) -> /model/turtlebot4/pose (tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-10] [INFO] [1699648676.413899469] [pose_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/model/standard_dock/pose (ignition.msgs.Pose_V) -> /model/standard_dock/pose (tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-11] [INFO] [1699648676.388577831] [odom_base_tf_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/model/turtlebot4/tf (ignition.msgs.Pose_V) -> /model/turtlebot4/tf (tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-12] [INFO] [1699648676.415609011] [bumper_contact_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/bumper_contact (ignition.msgs.Contacts) -> /bumper_contact (ros_gz_interfaces/msg/Contacts)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-13] [INFO] [1699648676.404330647] [cliff_front_left_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/base_link/sensor/cliff_front_left/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/base_link/sensor/cliff_front_left/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-14] [INFO] [1699648676.396475725] [cliff_front_right_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/base_link/sensor/cliff_front_right/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/base_link/sensor/cliff_front_right/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-15] [INFO] [1699648676.434581175] [cliff_side_left_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/base_link/sensor/cliff_side_left/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/base_link/sensor/cliff_side_left/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-16] [INFO] [1699648676.421925027] [cliff_side_right_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/base_link/sensor/cliff_side_right/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/base_link/sensor/cliff_side_right/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-17] [INFO] [1699648676.462396411] [ir_intensity_front_center_left_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_front_center_left/sensor/ir_intensity_front_center_left/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_front_center_left/sensor/ir_intensity_front_center_left/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-18] [INFO] [1699648676.438037837] [ir_intensity_front_center_right_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_front_center_right/sensor/ir_intensity_front_center_right/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_front_center_right/sensor/ir_intensity_front_center_right/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-19] [INFO] [1699648676.505582977] [ir_intensity_front_left_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_front_left/sensor/ir_intensity_front_left/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_front_left/sensor/ir_intensity_front_left/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-20] [INFO] [1699648676.527288571] [ir_intensity_front_right_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_front_right/sensor/ir_intensity_front_right/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_front_right/sensor/ir_intensity_front_right/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-21] [INFO] [1699648676.606438580] [ir_intensity_left_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_left/sensor/ir_intensity_left/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_left/sensor/ir_intensity_left/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-22] [INFO] [1699648676.611271896] [ir_intensity_right_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_right/sensor/ir_intensity_right/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_right/sensor/ir_intensity_right/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-23] [INFO] [1699648676.547373953] [ir_intensity_side_left_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_side_left/sensor/ir_intensity_side_left/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/ir_intensity_side_left/sensor/ir_intensity_side_left/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-26] [INFO] [1699648676.537248119] [hmi_buttons_msg_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/hmi/buttons (ignition.msgs.Int32) -> /hmi/buttons (std_msgs/msg/Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-27] [INFO] [1699648676.525080579] [hmi_led_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/led/power (std_msgs/msg/Int32) -> /hmi/led/power (ignition.msgs.Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-27] [INFO] [1699648676.532744189] [hmi_led_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/led/motors (std_msgs/msg/Int32) -> /hmi/led/motors (ignition.msgs.Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-27] [INFO] [1699648676.534361007] [hmi_led_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/led/comms (std_msgs/msg/Int32) -> /hmi/led/comms (ignition.msgs.Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-27] [INFO] [1699648676.536310605] [hmi_led_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/led/wifi (std_msgs/msg/Int32) -> /hmi/led/wifi (ignition.msgs.Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-27] [INFO] [1699648676.551567857] [hmi_led_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/led/battery (std_msgs/msg/Int32) -> /hmi/led/battery (ignition.msgs.Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-27] [INFO] [1699648676.572625572] [hmi_led_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/led/user1 (std_msgs/msg/Int32) -> /hmi/led/user1 (ignition.msgs.Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-27] [INFO] [1699648676.573226927] [hmi_led_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/led/user2 (std_msgs/msg/Int32) -> /hmi/led/user2 (ignition.msgs.Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[turtlebot4_node-30] [INFO] [1699648676.563515082] [turtlebot4_node]: Init Turtlebot4 Node Main
[static_transform_publisher-44] [WARN] [1699648676.609222075] []: Old-style arguments are deprecated; see --help for new-style arguments
[static_transform_publisher-45] [WARN] [1699648676.623906013] []: Old-style arguments are deprecated; see --help for new-style arguments
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Wrn] [gz.cc:99] Fuel world download failed because Fetch failed. Other errors
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] Unable to find or download file 
[ERROR] [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1]: process has died [pid 47187, exit code 255, cmd 'ruby $(which ign) gazebo warehouse.sdf -v 4 --gui-config /home/abdosalm/Github repos/SLAM-mapping-Robots/workspace/install/turtlebot4_ignition_bringup/share/turtlebot4_ignition_bringup/gui/standard/gui.config --force-version 6'].
[mock_publisher-37] [INFO] [1699648676.744083227] [mock_publisher]: Advertised mocked topic: slip_status
[parameter_bridge-24] [INFO] [1699648676.767249543] [buttons_msg_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/create3_buttons (ignition.msgs.Int32) -> /create3_buttons (std_msgs/msg/Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1699648676.770937360] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Advertised topic: hazard_detection
[wheel_status_publisher-36] [INFO] [1699648676.773493915] [wheel_status_publisher]: Advertised topic: wheel_vels
[wheel_status_publisher-36] [INFO] [1699648676.774061494] [wheel_status_publisher]: Advertised topic: wheel_ticks
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1699648676.774364667] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/bumper/event
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1699648676.777426750] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/cliff_front_left/event
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1699648676.777887855] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/cliff_front_right/event
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1699648676.778397177] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/cliff_side_left/event
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1699648676.778841579] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/cliff_side_right/event
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1699648676.779330633] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/wheel_drop/left_wheel/event
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1699648676.779684368] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/wheel_drop/right_wheel/event
[hazards_vector_publisher-33] [INFO] [1699648676.780051598] [hazards_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/backup_limit
[parameter_bridge-29] [INFO] [1699648676.812061956] [camera_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/sensor/rgbd_camera/image (ignition.msgs.Image) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/sensor/rgbd_camera/image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image)] (Lazy 0)
[kidnap_estimator_publisher-39] [INFO] [1699648676.817074154] [kidnap_estimator_publisher]: Advertised topic: kidnap_status
[kidnap_estimator_publisher-39] [INFO] [1699648676.817768472] [kidnap_estimator_publisher]: Subscription to topic: hazard_detection
[turtlebot4_node-30] [INFO] [1699648676.833756196] [turtlebot4_node]: Buttons Init
[static_transform_publisher-44] [INFO] [1699648676.836082121] [rplidar_stf]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-44] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-44] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-44] from 'rplidar_link' to 'turtlebot4/rplidar_link/rplidar'
[turtlebot4_node-30] [INFO] [1699648676.840261992] [turtlebot4_node]: Init Display
[static_transform_publisher-45] [INFO] [1699648676.850922474] [camera_stf]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-45] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-45] rotation: ('0.499952', '-0.500000', '0.500000', '0.500048')
[static_transform_publisher-45] from 'oakd_rgb_camera_optical_frame' to 'turtlebot4/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/rgbd_camera'
[parameter_bridge-28] [INFO] [1699648676.851519155] [lidar_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/rplidar_link/sensor/rplidar/scan (ignition.msgs.LaserScan) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/rplidar_link/sensor/rplidar/scan (sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-29] [INFO] [1699648676.854971829] [camera_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/sensor/rgbd_camera/depth_image (ignition.msgs.Image) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/sensor/rgbd_camera/depth_image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-29] [INFO] [1699648676.855614873] [camera_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/sensor/rgbd_camera/points (ignition.msgs.PointCloudPacked) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/sensor/rgbd_camera/points (sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-29] [INFO] [1699648676.856434110] [camera_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/sensor/rgbd_camera/camera_info (ignition.msgs.CameraInfo) -> /world/warehouse/model/turtlebot4/link/oakd_rgb_camera_frame/sensor/rgbd_camera/camera_info (sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo)] (Lazy 0)
[turtlebot4_node-30] [INFO] [1699648676.856874088] [turtlebot4_node]: Leds Init
[parameter_bridge-25] [INFO] [1699648676.884647930] [hmi_display_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/display/raw (std_msgs/msg/String) -> /hmi/display/raw (ignition.msgs.StringMsg)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-25] [INFO] [1699648676.887208318] [hmi_display_msg_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/hmi/display/selected (std_msgs/msg/Int32) -> /hmi/display/selected (ignition.msgs.Int32)] (Lazy 0)
[robot_state-38] [INFO] [1699648676.942738776] [robot_state]: Advertised topic: battery_state
[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34] [INFO] [1699648676.951454622] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher]: Advertised topic: ir_intensity
[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34] [INFO] [1699648676.952034237] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/ir_intensity_front_center_left
[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34] [INFO] [1699648676.952399772] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/ir_intensity_front_center_right
[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34] [INFO] [1699648676.952750283] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/ir_intensity_front_left
[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34] [INFO] [1699648676.953092106] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/ir_intensity_front_right
[robot_state-38] [INFO] [1699648676.953225184] [robot_state]: Subscription to topic: dock_status
[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34] [INFO] [1699648676.953429803] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/ir_intensity_left
[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34] [INFO] [1699648676.953761347] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/ir_intensity_right
[robot_state-38] [INFO] [1699648676.957443930] [robot_state]: Advertised topic: stop_status
[ui_mgr-40] [INFO] [1699648676.961821562] [ui_mgr]: Subscription to topic: cmd_lightring
[robot_state-38] [INFO] [1699648676.962935457] [robot_state]: Subscription to topic: odom
[ir_intensity_vector_publisher-34] [INFO] [1699648676.963436810] [ir_intensity_vector_publisher]: Subscription to topic: _internal/ir_intensity_side_left
[ui_mgr-40] [INFO] [1699648676.964104128] [ui_mgr]: Subscription to topic: cmd_audio
[motion_control-35] [INFO] [1699648677.016214199] [motion_control]: Enabling REFLEX_BUMP
[motion_control-35] [INFO] [1699648677.016384601] [motion_control]: Enabling REFLEX_CLIFF
[motion_control-35] [INFO] [1699648677.025890565] [motion_control]: Enabling REFLEX_STUCK
[motion_control-35] [INFO] [1699648677.027033022] [motion_control]: Enabling REFLEX_WHEEL_DROP
[joint_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1699648677.175418836] [joint_state_publisher]: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic...
[turtlebot4_node-30] [INFO] [1699648677.730755223] [turtlebot4_node]: Turtlebot4 standard running.
[parameter_bridge-27] [INFO] [1699648677.781401709] [hmi_led_msg_bridge]: Passing message from ROS std_msgs/msg/Int32 to Gazebo gz.msgs.Int32 (showing msg only once per type)
[parameter_bridge-25] [INFO] [1699648677.781533556] [hmi_display_msg_bridge]: Passing message from ROS std_msgs/msg/String to Gazebo gz.msgs.StringMsg (showing msg only once per type)
[parameter_bridge-25] [INFO] [1699648677.781617791] [hmi_display_msg_bridge]: Passing message from ROS std_msgs/msg/Int32 to Gazebo gz.msgs.Int32 (showing msg only once per type)
[spawner-32] [INFO] [1699648679.419453519] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[create-7] [INFO] [1699648681.353760872] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[create-8] [INFO] [1699648681.354417712] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[spawner-32] [INFO] [1699648681.443941166] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-32] [INFO] [1699648683.463901750] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-32] [INFO] [1699648685.484014982] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[create-7] [INFO] [1699648686.354372284] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[create-8] [INFO] [1699648686.354996458] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[spawner-32] [ERROR] [1699648687.501535689] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-32]: process has died [pid 47571, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_broadcaster -c controller_manager --ros-args -r __ns:=/'].
[INFO] [spawner-46]: process started with pid [47873]
[spawner-46] [INFO] [1699648689.893897561] [spawner_diffdrive_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[create-7] [INFO] [1699648691.354953594] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[create-8] [INFO] [1699648691.355459260] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[spawner-46] [INFO] [1699648691.915020875] [spawner_diffdrive_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-46] [INFO] [1699648693.936151939] [spawner_diffdrive_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-46] [INFO] [1699648695.956582581] [spawner_diffdrive_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[create-7] [INFO] [1699648696.355551080] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[create-8] [INFO] [1699648696.355962852] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[spawner-46] [ERROR] [1699648697.977331531] [spawner_diffdrive_controller]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-46]: process has died [pid 47873, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner diffdrive_controller -c controller_manager --ros-args -r __ns:=/ --params-file /opt/ros/humble/share/irobot_create_control/config/control.yaml'].
[create-7] [INFO] [1699648701.356163067] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[create-8] [INFO] [1699648701.356535983] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[create-7] [INFO] [1699648706.356723107] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
[create-8] [INFO] [1699648706.357086243] [ros_gz_sim]: Requesting list of world names.
```

so the terminal is stuck at this message due to multiple things I think due to :

```
[ros_ign_gazebo] is deprecated! Redirecting to use [ros_gz_sim] instead
```

or

```
[spawner_diffdrive_controller]: Controller manager not available
```

and I tried the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-humble-gazebo-ros2-control
```

but nothing changed.

where can my problem be?

Comment: It takes around 1-2 mins because it downloads models from fuels.gazebosim.org. Did you wait this long? Also, try changing the network and see if that helps

Comment: @GauravGupta, as you can see in the logs I found this error: `[ERROR] [1699648697.977331531] [spawner_diffdrive_controller]: Controller manager not available`
I only waited for 5 minutes but don't know if that error is normal or not.

Answer (score 1):

so, I managed to solve this problem, it was because I had missing packages not installed from the [common packages](https://turtlebot.github.io/turtlebot4-user-manual/software/turtlebot4_common.html), once I installed all the common packages not only the simulation package, I managed to to run the command `ros2 launch turtlebot4_ignition_bringup turtlebot4_ignition.launch.py` without any errors.